# D3js axis tick labels along with units as suffix

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have done most of my visualisation part but stuck with beautifying the ticks labels. I am trying to append units(i.e., kms or hPa or ℃ ) to my axis ticks. Tried tickFormat with a function but it seems like the code in the given function is not executed ( tried by giving console log stubs ). 
Actually I am trying with the following code:

```
   var pressure_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([30,980]).range([0,width]);
    var paxis = d3.axisBottom(pressure_scale).ticks(25).tickFormat(function(d){
                                                   var p = d3.format('.1f')(d);
                                                   console.log(p);
                                                   return p+' hPa';
                                                 })
```

What I am actually trying to get is,

30 hPa____60 hPa____90 hPa____120 hPa .......... ____980 hPa ( around 25 ticks)

But what I am actually getting is,

30____60____90____120 .......... ____980 ( around 25 ticks)

Please help me how to achieve the above tick label formatting.
I will also be glad if someone could clarify, why the console.log stub is not printing anything on console

P.S: I am using D3js V4 in my code

Comment: That code is working for me. Also, the console.log works just fine. Are you calling the axis? You'll have to add more details.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado.. Working .. ?? does the tick labels are displayed with units .. ?? what are all the details should I need to add .. ??

Comment: Yes, it's working. As I asked, are you calling the axis?

Comment: Yeah ... I am calling the axis ... This is how i am calling the axis 

svg.append('g')
         .attr('class','axis--py')
         .attr('transform','translate('+margin.pleft+',0)')
         .call(paxis)

P.S : I am using Opera, Does that matter .. ???

Comment: Well, as I said, you'll have to add more details, so we can check what's wrong. Please write a **minimal** version of the code you're using, with the part that call the axis.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ... Sorry it was my mistake, I was overwriting the axis varible twice. Hence, the changes made in before statement are not reflected. Thanks a Ton mate .. Happy coding :)